# How to convert this SQL Query on Code Igniter Model php code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
SELECT mahasiswa.nama, 
(select dosen.nama_dosen from mahasiswa,dosen 
where mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa ='MH000004' and mahasiswa.pembimbing_1 = dosen.id_dosen)
as pembimbing_pertama,
(select dosen.nama_dosen from mahasiswa,dosen 
where mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa ='MH000004' and mahasiswa.pembimbing_2 = dosen.id_dosen)
as pembimbing_kedua 
FROM mahasiswa where mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa ='MH000004'
```

Comment: codeigniter doesn't have a specific method for subqueries. i would suggest just doing `$this->db->query('yourstatement');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$mahasiswa = 'MH000004';
$this->db->select("SELECT mahasiswa.nama, 
(select dosen.nama_dosen from mahasiswa,dosen 
where mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa ='".$mahasiswa."' and mahasiswa.pembimbing_1 = dosen.id_dosen)
as pembimbing_pertama,
(select dosen.nama_dosen from mahasiswa,dosen 
where mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa ='".$mahasiswa."' and mahasiswa.pembimbing_2 = dosen.id_dosen)
as pembimbing_kedua");
$this->db->from('mahasiswa');
$this->db->where('mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa', $mahasiswa);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();//or row();
} else {
    return array();
}
```